# I have the following sequence and I want to prove the monotonicity of this sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, monotone-functions

The following sequence is provided and I am required to prove that the sequence is monotone and convergent.

$\left \{ \cos(\frac {1}{2}\arctan (\frac{-n}{2})^n)\right \}$

As far as convergence of the sequence is concerned, it will surely converge as for large $n$, the $\arctan (\frac{-n}{2} )^n$ part will tend to $π/2$. Consequently, the whole sequence will converge to $\frac{1}{√2}$. But, I am not able to prove the monotonicity of the given sequence. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that exponent $\;n\;$ on the arctangent's argument or on the whole arctan ? One must try to be as clear as possible when writing down messy stuff...

Comment: It's the exponent of its argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, observe that the values of the argument of the arctangent, namely $\;\left(-\frac n2\right)^n\;$ , are going "to jump" from positive to negative values (according to $\;n\;$ even or odd, of course), but we don't care as $\;\cos x\;$ is an *even* function. Second, we have that

$$-\frac\pi2<\arctan x<\frac\pi2\implies-\frac\pi4<\frac12\arctan x<\frac\pi4\;$$

so all the values of $\;\frac12\arctan\left(-\frac n2\right)^n\;$ are within the interval $\;\left[-\frac\pi4,\,\frac\pi4\right]\;$ . Thus, we can write

$$\cos\left[\frac12\arctan\left(\frac{-n}2\right)^n\right]=\cos\left[\frac12\arctan\left(\frac n2\right)^n\right]$$

and also: as $\;n\to\infty\;$ , we have that

$$\;\left(\frac n2\right)^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty\implies\frac12\arctan\left(\frac n2\right)^2\nearrow{}\frac\pi 4\implies\cos\left[\frac12\arctan\left(\frac n2\right)^n\right]\searrow\;\ldots$$

and you then get your sequence is monotone *descending* and obviously (?) bounded below, so it is convergent (in fact, the above already gives you the value of the limit, if you payed attention...)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the cosine, you can ignore the minus sign. Then $(\frac n2)^n$ is obviously a growing function for $n\ge1$. The arctangent is strictly growing on $\mathbb R$ and outputs a value in $[0,\frac\pi2)$. Finally, the cosine is decreasing in $[0,\frac\pi4)$, and bounded below.

The sequence very quickly tends to $\sqrt{\frac12}$.

[image]